# IE11 inteprets AJAX POST reply as string, despite being JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer-11

From an [JQuery AJAX post request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) the server sends me an reply that just says Hello, and I want to get that Hello as a string.

I wrote this code to get the text value:

```
var posting = $.post(
    "https://server/bla",
    {
        input: theinput
    }
);
posting.done(function( reply ) {
    console.log(reply);
    console.log(typeof reply);
    console.log(reply[0]);
}
```

It works perfectly on Firefox 55:

```
Array [ "Hello" ]
object
Hello
```

... but IE11 seems to believe it is a string (same code):

```
["Hello"]
string
"[\"Hello\"]"
```

I wrote a hackish workaround that just uses substring to remove the brackets and quotes at the beginning and end if the variable is a string, but it does not handle well quotes within the reply (`Hell"o` becomes `Hell\"o`).

Is there a cleaner solution?

By the way, here is the server side Java code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
jsonArray.put("Hello");
```

Comment: Try `$.getJSON` : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @JeremyThille good plan, but won't work for a POST request. Try using `$.ajax` and specifying `dataType: 'json'` explicitly.

Comment: @JeremyThille: That's for GET. My server only handles POST.

Comment: Ah damn, that's a POST request. My bad, ignore me.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but I've experienced a LOT of .NET based (HTTP) APIs doing the same thing. I first noticed it when my own input was reflected back, malformed. Any chance it has something to do with Microsoft's choice of encoding etc?

Answer (score 1):

As tipped by Rory, the datatype parameter helps here.

> dataType Type: String The type of data expected from the server.
>   Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

I rewrote the query part to this:

```
var posting = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<%=addResUrl%>",
  data: {
                input: theinput
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Note the `dataType: "json"`.

And now it works in IE11 the same way as in Firefox: The JSON is recognized as JSON.